# Column specified twice in insert statement

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have the following problem.

I have a mapped superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class MySuperClass {
  @Version
  private long version;
  private String foo;
  private String bar;
  // getter/setter omitted
}
```

and two entities, the second of which uses a shared primary key:

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity extends MySuperClass  {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  @OneToOne(mappedBy="main")
  private SecondaryEntity secondary;
  // getter/setter omitted
}

@Entity
public class SecondaryEntity extends MySuperClass  {
  @Id
  @OneToOne(optional=false)
  private MainEntity main;
  // getter/setter omitted
}
```

What I'm seing is that when I try to persist an instance of SecondaryEntity, EclipseLink generates a SQL statement that repeats the fields of the mapped superclass:

```
INSERT INTO SecondaryEntity ('field1', 'field2', 'version', 'foo', 'bar', 'field3', 'version', 'foo', 'bar', 'main_id') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Of course, MySql complains: Column 'version' specified twice
(I think it doesn't mention 'foo' and 'bar' because it stops at 'version', but they are repeated, too).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a problem in EclipseLink with the combination "shared primary key" and "mapped superclass"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not related to the use of both a "shared primary key" and of a "mapped superclass", but rather that `SecondaryEntity` had an embeddable field which erroneously extended the same mapped superclass, hence EclipseLink was trying to embed the mapped superclass attributes more than once in the SQL insert query.

Anyway, no error or warning was produced by EclipseLink at any stage in the modelling phase, at startup time or when I generated tables from entities. I filed [bug 456054](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=456054) in EclipseLink Bugzilla to track this problem.

Comment: Just wanted to say THANK YOU for posting this, was driving me nuts!